# Is it possible to flag or revert trivial non-suggested edits?

Tags: support, edits, revision-history, rollbacks, specific-edit

Is there some mechanism for flagging (or undoing outright) trivial edits to our posts? I recently had [this single-character edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30216000/revisions#) made to one of my posts, and I'm wondering is there's any way to cancel edits with exactly-zero significance and approaching-zero value (as with rejected suggested edits) without creating new history states (as is the case in a rollback).

Admittedly, part (well, *most*) of my frustration in this is I've been putting off more significant edits to this post because I wonder if they're legitimately worthwhile, and since I do not have much rep, I'm doing as much as I can to prevent this unusually-rewarding post from reaching its tenth edit. So when someone rolls up and **deletes a single duplicate space** and calls it an edit, I feel a little slighted especially since *duplicate   spaces    do    not     even    appear    on    the    post's    front    end.*

On a more noble note, I feel like it might do other users good to know when their objectively useless revisions have taken place, since it may not be obvious to them just yet (and, cynically, get them edit-banned if they turn out not to care).

I found [this MSE post on rejecting approved *suggested edits*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back), but this problem comes from a user who already has edit privileges and isn't using them correctly. Is there a mechanism for flagging useless edits or rejecting non-suggested edits *post-facto*? Has there been other discussion on this that I couldn't find?

**EDIT:** Actually it's a bit different from how I made this out to be: two line breaks were added and they really break up the continuity of the post and harm the readability of the thing, at least for me. I may go ahead with one of my other edits and just edit them out in the process.

Comment: I also see edits from >2K users with a tag removed/added while there is still code non-formatted, grammar errors... It's particulary annoying when it overlap one of my edit or it prevents me to post mine

Comment: If you hate it so much, you can Rollback to a previous revision. Click on the edited link, and have free.

Comment: @Soma Yes, but at least a retag has some merit, even if it's lazy and ignores other substantial problems. A single deleted space that didn't show up in the first place is genuinely worthless.

Comment: @Augusta, I said a tag because it was the last I seen but sometimes it is just formatting a part of the code, ignoring the rest

Comment: @BillWoodger And like I said, I want to avoid creating extra revision states. A rollback, as far as I know (and I may be wrong), *adds* states rather than *deleting* them, which I'm trying to avoid for my own stated reasons. :/

Comment: @Soma And I agree that these are wrong, but at least they have some arguable merit. The edit linked (which I just corrected to show the pointlessness of the thing properly) is *exactly one character's difference*, and the deleted character *is hidden from view on the front end* and has exactly zero value to the post.

Comment: " 
If you hate it so much..."

If you want to edit the post anyway, I can't remotely see a problem.  People make mistakes. Doesn't mean there's a *Mistake Police* available. If incensed, ping the editor. But don't be incensed in the content. It's not a biggie.

Comment: Worrying about the number of revision states suggests you're concerned about auto-CW, but that's no longer a concern these days: posts will never automatically convert to CW anymore.

Comment: @NathanTuggy ...oh. Well. That's my whole concern out the window. I'm still frustrated at people making pointless edits, but at least it's not going to create problems. Also, Bill, it's not so much a matter of "hating" it so much as it is about the CW thing, which I gather isn't liable to happen anymore.

Answer (score 16):

Anything that you could possibly do in response to such an edit would simply be you (and possibly others) wasting your time.  Trying to revert an edit that changed nothing is spending effort *accomplishing* nothing.  There's no need to roll it back, it's certainly not worth the time of a mod or employee to intervene, and it's not like the edit actually *harmed* anything.

Suggesting edits that aren't productive waste the time of the reviewers, lock the edit for a while, reward the editor when they didn't add value, etc., but a non-suggested edit has none of those problems.  The only real problem with an edit like this is that the post was inappropriately bumped in the activity views of questions, and, besides wasting your time, the only thing accomplished by trying to reverse it would be inappropriately bumping it again.

If you see someone making *lots* of edits of no value such that all of the posts are disrupting the activity view, *then* it could be worth flagging for a mod attention, but unless it's a large number of edits, it's just not worth anyone's time to think about it.

Comment: That's why I haven't done anything, really. I actually took a second look at the post and realized that he added a line break or two (still pointless, only this time it's actually slightly harmful), which actually *is* ugly and harms the post's continuity, but there isn't much to do about it since it's fairly minor. I'm going to update my original post with this observation in a moment.

Comment: All the same, it'd still be useful to flag this kind of thing (or have some other mechanism) if it happens elsewhere, so that hopefully something pointful can be done about it without having to make a post on Meta.

Comment: @Augusta Like I said, if you see someone making a *lot* of edits, like filling up the front page full of posts from minor edits, then go ahead and flag.  When it's just one edit, basically anything you do to try to "fix" the problem will cause more of a disruption than the edit you're responding to.

Comment: Yes, but *what* do I flag? Can individual edits be flagged, or is it the whole post with a custom rationale?

Comment: @Augusta You would flag the post, if you *really* needed moderator attention.  Again, this edit most certainly doesn't merit it.

Comment: Yes, no, I get that, although I would argue that any edit which is both trivial *and* harmful may deserve attention. I'm just going to fix this one since there are other things I want to do to it anyway, and if the harmful parts (that being the line breaks, rather than the extra space) are re-inserted, I'll flag that. If it was just the space as I had suspected, I'd ignore it, but it turns out it was more and worse than that.

Comment: Or actually, I don't know-- for vandalism to be vandalism, does it have to be meet some criterion for minimum severity? I get that moderators are busy and small problems distract from big ones, but how small is 'small'? (I mean, not the space thing, which is invisible, but the line breaks, which are (were) actually doing some (smallish) harm.)

Comment: @Augusta If you feel that the user was intentionally vandalizing the post by actively harming it *intentionally*, then flag for a mod.  If you think he was trying to improve the post, and thought that the line break helped, but it simply didn't, then just edit the post to fix it, optionally commenting to the user to explain why their edit was (a tiny bit) harmful.  Personally I looked at the edit and I think those line breaks helped, rather than harmed, although it wasn't *significant*, I do think that it's better with that change.

Comment: Worth knowing! I found the line breaks a bit jarring and out of sorts with the style of the rest of the post, so I took them out, but I only bothered because I had other, more significant things to say. That's good input, though, and thanks for it!