# Should I rollback trivial edits from >2k rep users, when there are multiple such edits?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, trivial

A user who had just passed 2k rep made a [trivial edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69943576/revisions) (Revision 3) on a question. I was curious, should I roll this back or leave it as is? They simply changed "I am" to "I'm". My idea would be to edit it back (not rollback so I can put a reason) and put the reason as "do not make trivial edits", though it wouldn't notify the editor.

After looking into their edit history, it seems that this was not the only post they did this on. What should I do in this case? Should I rollback the edits I've seen, or leave a comment for the user, or raise a custom flag?

Comment: No, via: [Are trivial edits okay if I have full editing privileges?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312701/are-trivial-edits-okay-if-i-have-full-editing-privileges)

Comment: I'd rather raise a custom mod flag, this is not a single edit, but a system which floods the page with edits: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8172439/kai?tab=activity

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I don't follow. What would you raise a custom flag for? There's nothing wrong with making "trivial" edits, so long as the edits are an improvement, or at least, don't make the post worse.

Comment: The edit's not exactly an improvement... they just changed "I am" to "I'm"

Comment: @cigien Changing correct grammar to some other correct grammar is not an improvement, it just spams the front page with edits. Same for all the white space edits. And making sure that unnecessary fluff is capitalised is also not helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69946530/revisions

Comment: "Trivial edits" are discouraged for two reasons: 1) They clog up the suggested edits queue and 2) Posts _usually_ have more to fix than just a single character. If someone is over 2k, the first problem is irrelevant, and they're trusted to address the second problem. If they don't do that, then _that_ might be time for a rollback or modflag, but in general, assume good intent unless there's a pattern of poor behavior on behalf of the editor.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz If there's a pattern of trivial edits, then I guess you could raise a custom flag. That's not what the OP is asking about though, OP is asking about a single edit. Also, flooding the active page is not really a big issue on SO, given the amount of activity that takes place anyway.

Comment: @cigien Yes, the OP asked about a single edit and I answered that its not just a single edit, but a constant stream of such edits

Comment: @MrMythical Let's avoid linking to multiple examples by the user, since that's not what this question is about. As mentioned by samcarter, if there's a pattern of trivial edits, you can go ahead and raise a custom flag. Alternatively, you could edit the question to be about a pattern of edits, as opposed to a single edit, but check if there's a duplicate on meta for that as well.

Comment: So... the general case, resounding no. _This_ case? I agree with modflagging this user's edits, they appear to have a history of specifically _just_ changing "I am" to "I'm" in posts, which is absolutely no improvement.

Comment: This meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303373 appears to be a duplicate. Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403955

Comment: @cigien that's about suggested edits, while this user just got above 2k rep, but [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294823/is-it-possible-to-flag-or-revert-trivial-non-suggested-edits) one seems to be directed at non-suggested edits

Comment: @MrMythical Yeah, the first link isn't great. The second one seems much more specific (it even mentions "I am" -> "I'm"). All those posts cover the issue anyway.

Comment: You can roll back with a reason by clicking edit instead of rollback at the target version & editing only the summary field. The post is rolled back with your summary appended to the default rollback summary text. (This is actually documented in an obscure & unclear meta post.)

Comment: As a post owner, I would not be comfortable with a trivial edit made for the sole purpose to revert a trivial edit and lecturing a user who likely won't see the comment anyway. Using an edit to revert the change is just as useless and opiniated as the original edit; using the edit message for communication seems to border on misuse.